# Facebook iframe - how to send form (POST method)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-iframe

I have very simple form (the file is called `message.php`):

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
<form method="post" target="_top" action="<?php echo CANVAS_URL;?>message.php">
  <input type="text" name="your_name" />
  <input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['signed_request'];?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

I found one solution of this issue - put into the form hidden input with the `signed_request` - I did it but unfortunately I am still facing with this problem -- I cannot retrieve sent POST data.

If I change the method to `method="get"`, everything is working well, but I would need to data from POST.

Could anyone help me, how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I don't believe you need to use `target` in FB canvas aps anymore. Also a form ID would be good.

```
<form method="POST" id="my_form" action="message.php">
    <input type="text" name="your_name" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php print $_POST["signed_request"] ?>" name="signed_request" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but unfortunately, this didn't help me. Still can't retrieve data from $_POST

Comment: Hmm. The only thing different is that I'm not using `<?php echo CANVAS_URL;?>` in front of the file name. If this code is in message.php then why would it need to be there? Baring that, perhaps you can post more of your code or link to a live example?

Answer (score 1):

POSTing to Canvas URLs (as in http://apps.facebook.com/namespace) is simply not supported.
But why post to the top window instead of simply staying within the iframe? It's way better as it doesn't require the entire page to be reloaded, only the iframe.